# Suppress Status Output in Django

Tags: django

I tried to find this, but I'm probably not searching the right way. When I run my Django app, I get a record printed to the error output every time an endpoint is called, similar to:

> [20/Jun/2019 09:45:37] "GET /analyst/run_session/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1271

The problem is, I have a call set up every second to refresh data from the api, so my console is being flooded by these entries.

I have tried setting `DEBUG=False`, and setting `MESSAGE_LEVEL=message_constants.ERROR`, but it doesn't seem to suppress these entries. Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

This is done via logging configs, you will need to override the config for the [`django.server` logger](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/logging/#django-server-logger).

For example:

```
LOGGING = {
  'version': 1,
  'disable_existing_loggers': False,
  'loggers': {
    'django.server': {
      'level': 'ERROR'
    }
  }
}
```